# Error Domain when using GET method in the http request

Tags: ios, swift

i am new in programming, and now i am learning to build an iOS app using PHP as the backend server.

as far as i know, in http method, if I use GET method, it is equal to write a query in the browser.

let say i want to send 'id' as the query item to get JSON response from a server, i can write like this in the browser

http:/website.com/post.php?id=23

I build my backend using PHP, and to catch that id, i use $_REQUEST in the server side code ($_REQUEST can accept GET & POST method as far as i know).

i can get the JSON data response from server when i access that path using the browser.

but, when i am trying to send that query from my iOS app using GET method, i have an error

> Error : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

but when I change that http method to POST, it is worked seamlessly. here is the method activated when i want send the request in my iOS app. I just want to fetch the data, not to create new a data in the database.

```
func loadPost() {
    let id = userInfo!["id"] as! String

    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/Twitter/post.php")

    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET" <--- if i change this to POST, it is worked

    let body = "id=\(id)"
    request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                    guard let parsedJSON = json else {
                        print ("error while parsing JSON")
                        return
                    }
                    print(parsedJSON)
                } catch {
                    print ("Error : \(error)")
                }
            }
        } else {  
            print ("Error : \(error!)")
        }  
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

What went wrong in here? Why does it only work if I use POST method, not GET method ?

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift, use `[String:Any]` when parsing JSON dictionaries and don't use `.mutableContainers` as it has no effect in Swift.

Comment: If you try your URL in Safari, does it work? Do you get back the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the data via the body of the request. By default a `GET` will expect parameters as a query string parameter, where as a `POST` will expect them via the body

https://secure.php.net/manual/it/function.http-get-request-body.php